# Is it possible to have phase shift with only passive (resistor, cap, inductor) components?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, inductor, oscillator

I know that this can be done somewhat because voltage will lag current on a capacitor etc. But I want to see if it is possible to take an AC signal and output the same signal but with some chosen phase shift (x degrees) using only these components, I know it can be done by adding op amp or transistor.

What I want is to sample an AC signal at the same frequency but at different phases, ideally more than 2. So sample at 50degrees, 60 degrees, 90 degrees etc.

Comment: This all depends on the load for the filter or delay line (?)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand

Comment: You can create a phase shift with just a trace, no need for any resistor, capacitor or inductor.

Comment: Basically, you can do it but there are limitations. If your sample rate is high (RF) the easiest thing might be to use a delay line to introduce a phase difference between your two sample clocks.

Comment: What is needed to make delay line?

Comment: It could be a length of coaxial cable. For example if a signal travels at 150 m/us in coax, then that means there is a delay of about 6.7ns/meter. If the period of the signal is 10ns (100 MHz) then 1 meter is a phase shift of 6.7/10*360=240 degrees. That speed is approximately correct, but you would want to double check it if you are actually going to do this.

Comment: A delay line is any controlled impedance lossless length of wire or the equivalent cut in LCLC all pass filter . The answer given below is a Low pass filter which delays less then cutoff f a fixed amount.

Answer (score 1):

Any combination of resistor (R) with inductor (L), R with capacitor (C), LC, or RLC can make a phase shift.

If the amplitude drop is not a concern, for all these circuits, the answer is 'YES'. But if you need the same amplitude and don't want to use any active circuits, you need to eliminate the resistor.

You will be left with an LC or CL circuit. I recommend the LC circuit. The L must be in series and the C in parallel to your output.

Again, if you're not using any active component, notice that any current drain from C will result in different phase shifts.

If you consider an open circuit like this:

[image: LC Arrary]

the shift (delay) will be like this:

[image: Delay]

Read more in this PDF: [Delay Lines](http://web.hep.uiuc.edu/Engin/CDF/CMU/asd2_web/data_sheets_misc/rhombus.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an RC circuit can be used to shift phase. Look up a "phase shift oscillator," which typically uses 3 sections to shift 180 degrees at a specific frequency. You can even get a small amount of voltage gain out of cascaded RC sections (at a specific frequency).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get phase shift using 100 pf capacitor in series  & 330 k resistor in parallel with source of 230 V AC single phase supply with load of two identical universal small motors.one motor fed from R Phase direct (normal) but other motor through RC expecting its advanced phase angle by 60 degree & synchronizing with R phase (Parallel operation of R & Y Phase) but it didn't happen.I got full line to line voltage of 415 volts between R & Y Phases.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).